# Imacros Javascript Eval in Extraction remove part of text

Tags: javascript, regex, text, eval, imacros

I need to remove a part of text extracted by imacros.

The text estracted can be change.

Example texts extracted by imacros:

```
THE FIRST SENTENCE - THE SECONDS SENTENCE
THE FIRST WORD - THE SECONDS WORD
THE FIRST NAME - THE SECONDS NAME
CACAO - COLA
```

I need to remove the part BEFORE - AND remove the part AFTER -

1° Eval script need to take:

```
THE FIRST SENTENCE
THE FIRST WORD
THE FIRST NAME
CACAO
```

2° Eval script need to take

```
THE SECONDS SENTENCE
THE SECONDS WORD
THE SECONDS NAME
COLA
```

I need with Eval to remove the part BEFORE - and remove the part AFTER - using 2 different eval script.

I use an eval javascript like this but I need to create a regex expression to remove only the part before and after - (spaces included)

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/[\\TEXTTOREMOVE|TEXTTOREMOVE|TEXTTOREMOVE|TEXTTOREMOVE|TEXTTOREMOVE|]/g, '');")

SET !VAR2 EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/[\\TEXTTOREMOVE|TEXTTOREMOVE|TEXTTOREMOVE|TEXTTOREMOVE|TEXTTOREMOVE|]/g, '');")
```

Any suggestion please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you can solve the issue without regular expressions:

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.split('-')[0].trim();")
SET !VAR2 EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.split('-')[1].trim();")
```

Comment: Your solution is perfect working well, many thanks for helped me. Have a nice day